# How to handle OnClick command of UserControl using command in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I want to handle some `Button.Click` events in a page that implements a `UserControl`.

The `UserControl` looks like this:

```xml
<UserControl>
    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

        <Button Command="{Binding ButtonClickedCommand, Source={RelativeSource Self}}" />

    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

and the code behind:

```cs
public partial class MapUserControl : UserControl
{

    public MapTabBar()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public ICommand ButtonClickedCommand
    {
        get { return (ICommand)GetValue(ButtonClickedCommandProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ButtonClickedCommandProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ButtonClickedCommandProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "ButtonClickedCommandProperty", 
        typeof(ICommand), 
        typeof(MapTabBar), 
        new PropertyMetadata(null));

}
```

I use this `UserControl` in my `MainPage.xaml:`

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">

    <maps:Map x:Name="Map" ZoomLevel="7" />

    <local:MapUserControl
        ButtonClickedCommand="{Binding ???}" />

</Grid>
```

How do I bind this `ButtonClickedCommand` to my function in the `MainPage.xaml.cs`:

```cs
    protected void Button_Clicked()
    {
        MessageBox.Show("button clicked");
    }
```

Ultimately I want to manipulate the Map in my MainPage (center something, filter, reload). Is this the right approach – or is there another way?

Comment: Is there anything else in your UserControl, or did you include the entire thing?

Comment: @ShawnKendrot The UserControl contains an Image, 4 custom buttons and another UserControl (with some Grids). Nothing too complicated, but I want to keep my Page as clean as possible and I eventually want to reuse the MapUserControl - for now I coppy-pasted the whole UserControl into my page

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your UserControl

```
<!-- xaml -->
<Button Click="OnButtonClicked"/>


// Code behind
private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    if(ButtonClickedCommand != null)
    {
        ButtonClickedCommand.Execute(null);
    }
}
```

---

Another solution is to allow your map tools control the map itself. You would need to set a DP on the map tools object (side note: Better to create a custom control rather than a USerControl).

```
// MapTools
public Map Map
{
    get { return (Map)GetValue(MapProperty); }
    set { SetValue(MapProperty, value); }
}

public static readonly DependencyProperty MapProperty =
    DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Map", 
    typeof(Map), 
    typeof(MapTools), 
    new PropertyMetadata(null));

private void OnButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs)
{
    // Manipulate map
}
```

Then in your page that is using it

```
<Grid>
    <maps:Map x:Name="MyMap"\>
    <mytools:MapTools Map="{Binding ElementName=MyMap}"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: where do I put the OnButtonClicked EventHandler? If I do this in the UserControl, where do I listen to the Event in the MainPage.xaml- or if I do this in the MainPage, how can I handle the OnButtonClicked Event in the MainPage (I need the page context to access and manipulate my map)?

Comment: The example above is only for the UserControl. Your page that hosts the UserControl would use commanding. It would bind to a property on your view model that is an ICommand. See [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms752308(v=vs.90).aspx) for more info on commanding

Comment: Added another answer along with the original

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is just register a function of your main page and not having the hability to bind a Command from your viewModel, I don't see any use for you to use command, just use events:

In your UserControl define:

```
public event RoutedEventHandler ButtonClicked;

    private void MyButtonClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (ButtonClicked != null)
        {
            ButtonClicked(sender, e);
        }

    }
```

And then on you main page just use it like this:

```
    <local:MapUserControl ButtonClicked="Button_Clicked"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

**MainPage.xaml**, I am binding a login UserControl
by using the **namespace** : xmlns:UC="clr-namespace:Test.Views" , since I have my usercontrol in Folder named "**Views**".

```
<ScrollViewer>
<UC:Login BtnLoginClick="Login_BtnLoginClick"/>
</ScrollViewer>
```

**Login.cs**

```
public partial class Login : UserControl    {

    public event EventHandler BtnLoginClick;

    public Login()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        string userName = txtUserName.Text;
        string userPassword = txtUserPassword.Password.Trim();
        if (userName != null && userName != string.Empty && userPassword != null &&       userPassword != string.Empty)
        {
            if (this.BtnLoginClick != null)
            {
                this.BtnLoginClick(this, e);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Invalid username or password");
        }
    }
```

}

Finally, dont forgot to use the event handler in MainPage.xaml to capture the button clicked event from Login Usercontrol to do other actions.

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<UC:Login BtnLoginClick="Login_BtnLoginClick"/>
```

Here "BtnLoginClick" its an event Handler defined in the Login.xaml[User Control].

Create new event for this "BtnLoginClick" event as i created "Login_BtnLoginClick".

**MainPage.cs**

```
private void Login_BtnLoginClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
Messagebox.Show("Event captured successfully");
////Here you can add your stuffs...     
}
```